# Different variables for different subgroups of linear model

Tags: multiple-regression, least-squares, multilevel-analysis

Let's say I have a multiple linear model for a population of the form

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + e$

There is a third variable I want to introduce that I believe significantly explains variance in $y$, but only for a small subset of the population - say 5-10%.

My understanding is that I could set this third variable to 0 for members not in this subset, but that would understate the effect of this variable for the desired subset since the variable explains no variance in $y$ for the remainder of the population.

Is there a good way to capture the true effects of this third variable on a subset of data in context of the rest of the model?

Comment: On what basis do you believe this *indicator* variable would "understate" the effect?  "Explains no variance ... for the remainder of the population" is meaningless because the effect is irrelevant for the remainder.

Comment: It's not an indicator variable. It can take on any range of values, not just 1 or 0. And my intuition is that if you were to run a regression with all 3 variables *only* on the subset, the variable would explain much more variance than if you were to run it on the full population with the variable filled in with 0's outside the subset.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Your intuition might be relying on some unstated conditions.  The third variable will reduce the response variance by exactly the same amount if it were used separately in the subpopulation or included in the overall model.

Comment: It sounds like you may want an interaction between this new indicator and the original variable.